# android how to stop mHandler.postDelayed

Tags: android

I have an application where I use mHandler as a timer.... It works fine and then Runnable MuPdeteTimeTask works.... Here is a code...

```
    mHandlerTime.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeOutTask);
                mHandlerTime.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeOutTask, delay_timeoutzz);
```

....................................

```
    private Runnable mUpdateTimeOutTask = new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TimeOut of session is reached! Session will be force closed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               new UploadTask().onCancelled();
                       }
        };
```

How could I stop it or want to define new meanings of "delay"????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can surely do something like this,

Take Two Variables,

```
boolean delayedAgain = false;
long newDelayedTimeFromNow=5000;
```

Then in your runnable apply logic as,

```
Runnable  mUpdateTimeOutTask = new Runnable() {             
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(delayedAgain)
                {
                    delayedAgain = false;
                    mHandlerTime.postDelayed(this, newDelayedTimeFromNow);  
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    // DO JOB ON TIME.
                }                   
            }
        };
```

And now from your another task,

```
if(somethingIsDone)
{
  delayedAgain = true;
  newDelayedTimeFromNow = 3000;
}
```